# Run python script in different shell levels

Tags: python, subprocess

//Starting a perl script

> os.system('./start.pl')

//Make command used and o/p redirected to a file

> os.system('make > file')

I am a beginner in Python.

whenever i run the perl script(start.pl), new subprocess is created and the shell enters into new subshell and rest lines in the python script goes un-entered.

Kindly help me to run other commands even after shell enters into new sub shell.

Comment: Do you specifically need to run in different process, then use os.fork or you can try os.popen to have better handling of the inpout/output/error streams.

Comment: Though i use fork, when env changes, it remains in the new sub shell. iff i exit the sub shell rest of commands get executed